# Pi Cron Job Fails to Run

Tags: cron, raspbian

Hoping someone can help with a crontab issue I am having on the pi.
I have a program, rf24_receiver.py, that resides in the  /home/pi directory.  When run from terminal, it requires sudo to run.  So with this command on terminal,
`sudo python3 rf24_receiver.py`, the program executes perfectly.
However, I need to run it on a schedule, so I tried the following without success.

```
crontab -e
*/30 * * * * sudo python3 /home/pi/rf24_receiver.py >> /home/pi/rf24_receiver.py.log 2>&1
```

Then I tried this

```
*/30 * * * * python3 /home/pi/rf24_receiver.py >> /home/pi/rf24_receiver.py.log 2>&1
```

Then I tried this

```
sudo crontab -e
*/30 * * * * sudo python3 /home/pi/rf24_receiver.py >> /home/pi/rf24_receiver.py.log 2>&1
```

Then I tried this

```
*/30 * * * * python3 /home/pi/rf24_receiver.py >> /home/pi/rf24_receiver.py.log 2>&1
```

No success with any of the above.  I hope this is the right place to post this.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Jim.  Thanks, new to the forum and I could not figure how to make the question more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother the forum with this question.  I am not sure why I got this command to work under sudo crontab -e:

*/29 */1 * * * sudo python3 /home/pi/rf24_receiverR3.py >> /home/pi/rf24_receiverR3.py.log 2>&1

I did a reboot and it seemed to work after that.